# Valor do checkbox está nulo, Column 'situacao' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Tenho um campo  `$table->enum('situacao', ['ativo', 'exonerado']);`.

Criei um checkbox pra fazer o cadastro, mas ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> 1048 Column 'situacao' cannot be null.

**Como posso resolver?**

O checkbox está assim:

`{!! Form::checkbox('situacao', '1') !!}`

Já a captura está assim:

```
$civil = new civil;
$civil->situacao = $request->situacao;
$civil->save();
```

Comment: Dá esse erro só quando o checkbox não está marcado?

Comment: Vc pode começar com um checkbox pré-selecionado, e permitir apenas trocar a seleção não permitindo que fiquem todos desmarcados

Comment: Deu certo? .......

Answer (score 0):

O correto nesse caso seria com `select` e não com `checkbox`, porque, forçaria a escolha do texto *ativo* ou *exonerado* com a estrutura proposta, exemplo:

```
{{ Form::select('situacao', ['ativo' => 'ativo','exonerado' => 'exonerado']) }}
```

Não passaria pelo mesmo problema, mas, mesmo assim quiser continuar com `checkbox` teria então que conferir se foi escolhido ou não, se for escolhido seria o valor *ativo* se não *exonerado*:

```
$civil = new civil;
$civil->situacao = $request->has('situacao') ? 'ativo' : 'exonerado';
$civil->save();
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Creating a Select Box Field](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field)</sub>